# SQLAlchemy: Effect of 2 session objects?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Will the following use 2 DB connections from the connection pool because of the useage of 2 `session` calls?

```
users_from_contacts = db.session.query(User).join(Email, Email.user_id == User.id).join(Contacts, Contacts.email_id = Email.id)
users_from_past = db.session.query(User).join(Group, Group.user_id == User.id)

all_users = users_from_contacts.union_all(users_from_past).all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, for one because the `Session` runs in an ongoing, single-connection transaction unless `autocommit` is set to the non-default of `True`, and two because there is only one SQL query emitted from the code above, when the `.all()` method is called.

relevant docs:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#managing-transactions

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#returning-lists-and-scalars

Comment: Thanks. Time for me to add some tracings to my connection pool to see where theyrre all going.